# Classic ASP Request.form gets no update when using onsubmit with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a simple form where I use Javascript to execute a search on a database.

```
<form id="searchForm" onsubmit="return searchTree(this);" method="post" class="form-poshytip">
 <input type="text" name="searchbox" placeholder="zoek hier je product..." id="searchField" />
 <input type="image" value="Zoeken" name="submit" src="../img/Zoeken.PNG" alt="submit" />
</form>
```

In Javascript I connect to Access using Classic ASP.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function searchTree(form) {
<% Dim rsTreeview2 %>
<% Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") %>
<% adoCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("...") %>
<% Set rsTreeview2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") %>
<% strSQL = "SELECT tblTreeview_nl.volgnr, tblTreeview_nl.lid_van, tblTreeview_nl.omschrijving, tblTreeview_nl.doctype, tblTreeview_nl.docnaam FROM tblTreeview_nl WHERE tblTreeview_nl.omschrijving LIKE '%" & request.form("searchbox") & "%'"%>
<% rsTreeview2.Open strSQL, adoCon %>
...
<% rsTreeview2.Close %>
<% Set rsTreeview2 = Nothing %>
<% Set adoCon = Nothing %>
return false;
};
</script>
```

The first time I click the button I get the correct value from the textbox using request.form("searchbox"), but if I click the button again after changing the textbox, request.form("searchbox") contains the old value. How can I obtain the current value from the textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew, where to start...

- First; remove your database name from this post, because I can find
  it and download it.
- Second; escape your search term, to prevent SQL Injection

The problem is you use `onsubmit="return searchTree(this);"`. This means that if the function returns FALSE, the form is NOT submitted. 
In your script I see the function always returns false, so the form will not really submit.

I'm not sure why you have put all of the ASP/vbscript code inside your javascript tag, but I presume you output some javascript code directly into your script tags to create a tree-view. This is fine, but for testing purposes I would start with just outputting it on screen, instead of inside script tags, and work from that.

I have reformatted your code somewhat to do just that. There is also a quick fix in there for the SQL injection problem you have.

hope this helps,

Erik

```
<%

function hasValue(value)
    hasValue = NOT(isNull(value) OR value="")
end function

function escape(inputValue)
    if hasValue(inputValue) then
        escape  = Replace(inputValue, "'", "''")
    end if
end function

function recordsetToString(rs)
    Dim objField
    recordsetToString   = ""
    recordsetToString   = recordsetToString & "<table class=""dbgtable"">"
    recordsetToString   = recordsetToString & "<tr>" & vbNewLine
    For Each objField in rs.Fields
    recordsetToString   = recordsetToString & "<th>" & objField.Name & "</th>" & vbNewLine
    Next
    recordsetToString   = recordsetToString & "</tr>" & vbNewLine
    if NOT rs.EOF then
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            recordsetToString   = recordsetToString & "<tr>" & vbNewLine
            For Each objField in rs.Fields
                recordsetToString   = recordsetToString & "<td>"
                if isNull(objField.Value) then
                    recordsetToString   = recordsetToString & "<i>NULL</i>"
                else
                    if vartype(objField.Value)>20 then
                        recordsetToString   = recordsetToString & typename(objField.Value)
                    else
                        recordsetToString   = recordsetToString & objField.Value
                    end if
                end if
                recordsetToString   = recordsetToString & "</td>" & vbNewLine
            Next
            recordsetToString   = recordsetToString & "</tr>" & vbNewLine
        rs.MoveNext
        Loop
        if rs.CursorType>0 then
            rs.movefirst
        end if
    end if
    recordsetToString   = recordsetToString & "</table>" & vbNewLine
end function

if hasValue(request.form("searchbox")) Then
Dim adoCon
Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
    adoCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("[PATH_TO_DATBASE]") 
    Dim rsTreeview2
    Set rsTreeview2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
        strSQL = "SELECT tblTreeview_nl.volgnr, tblTreeview_nl.lid_van, tblTreeview_nl.omschrijving, tblTreeview_nl.doctype, tblTreeview_nl.docnaam FROM tblTreeview_nl WHERE tblTreeview_nl.omschrijving LIKE '%" & escape(request.form("searchbox")) & "%'"
        rsTreeview2.Open strSQL, adoCon 
            recordsetToString(rsTreeview2)
        rsTreeview2.Close 
    Set rsTreeview2 = Nothing 
Set adoCon = Nothing 
end if
%>


<script language="JavaScript">
function searchTree(form) {
    return false;
};
</script>
```

Comment: The code above should work, just don't return false from your javascript function. Return True to make the form submit.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've implemented the escape function. 
However it's not clear to me how your soluton will always get the current value from the textbox. When will the code "if hasValue(request.form("searchbox"))" be executed? Don't we have to put it in the searchTree function?

Comment: The problem is that after return true the page will be reloaded, and the treeview i've just written will be gone. How can I prevent that?

Comment: The first time you load the page, the search box will be empty and you can fill it out. When you click 'submit' the page will POST to itself, you don't actually need the 'onsubmit' function for that, remove it if you like.
When the page POSTs to itself, it will reload, but the difference is that the value you put in the textbox will now be passed along with it, so "if hasValue(request.form("searchbox"))..." will become TRUE, and the recordset will load, using the value you put in the textbox. You can't prevent the page reloading when you submit, you will have to re-draw the treeview.

Comment: If you want the tree to stay, and you want to search the existing tree, you will have to do it entirely in javascript. You don't need a form, just a textbox and a button, and onclick of the button use the text in the textbox to search in your treeview. but that's a completely different topic :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I couldn't get it to work, so I've done it in javascript (no form, search within the tree and without connecting to the database). :-)